# Ruby on Rails - Associating a service with a shop. How to integrate this relationship in the 'create' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating an app where I have a 'Shop' model, which is associated with a 'Service' model (For example, a shop might offer different services which can be added by the shop owner only - such as an oil change, new tires, window tinting etc.)

I believe I have the relationship sorted:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shop
end
```

and

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :services
end
```

However I'm not sure how to add this association in the 'Service' create method so that 'service' belongs only to 'shop'

I'd also like to display all related services on the Shop 'show' page.

I'm in the 'Show' view of Shop, and I want to add a service, how can I pass the shop_id into the service and what files would I have to change?

The create method is just the bog standard scaffold one:

```
def create
    @service = Service.new(service_params)
    @service.save
    respond_with(@service)
end
```

And the database looks like this:
Shops:

```
class CreateShops < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :shops do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :phone
      t.string :email
      t.string :website
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and Services:

```
class CreateServices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :services do |t|
      t.string :category
      t.integer :shop_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Any help would be very appreciated. I guess i'm just not getting how to pass the relationship information correctly.
Cheers!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by: `However I'm not sure how to add this association in the 'Service' create method so that 'service' belongs only to 'cars'.` Do you have a cars model? Do shops offer other services like for example lawn mowing? Respond by editing your question!

Comment: Cheers for that - updated and clarified. Had cars on the brain.

Comment: What are your service_params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need a set of nested routes for shops & services:

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :shops do
  resources :services
end
```

This creates routes for `services` nested under `shop`:

```
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
    shop_services GET    /shops/:shop_id/services(.:format)          services#index
                  POST   /shops/:shop_id/services(.:format)          services#create
 new_shop_service GET    /shops/:shop_id/services/new(.:format)      services#new
edit_shop_service GET    /shops/:shop_id/services/:id/edit(.:format) services#edit
     shop_service GET    /shops/:shop_id/services/:id(.:format)      services#show
                  PATCH  /shops/:shop_id/services/:id(.:format)      services#update
                  PUT    /shops/:shop_id/services/:id(.:format)      services#update
                  DELETE /shops/:shop_id/services/:id(.:format)      services#destroy
            shops GET    /shops(.:format)                            shops#index
                  POST   /shops(.:format)                            shops#create
         new_shop GET    /shops/new(.:format)                        shops#new
        edit_shop GET    /shops/:id/edit(.:format)                   shops#edit
             shop GET    /shops/:id(.:format)                        shops#show
                  PATCH  /shops/:id(.:format)                        shops#update
                  PUT    /shops/:id(.:format)                        shops#update
                  DELETE /shops/:id(.:format)                        shops#destroy
```

If look at the parameters for the services routes you can see that there is a `:shop_id` parameter.

We can use this in our `ServicesController` to set the shop before each action:

```
class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_shop

  # GET /shops/:shop_id/services/new
  def new 
    @service = @shop.services.new
  end

  # POST /shops/:shop_id/services
  def create
    @service = @shop.services.new(service_params)
    # ... @todo validate and save
  end

  private
  def service_params
    params.require(:service).permit(:category)
  end

  def set_shop
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
  end
end
```

In your views you need to change your forms somewhat so that `form_for` uses the correct path.

```
<!-- views/services/new.html.erb -->
<h1>Add a service to <%= @service.shop.name %></h1>
<%= form_for([@service.shop, @service]) do |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, Papir tiger. Worked nicely! Just had to change the 'create' method for services to redirect to the related 'shop'.